# Why am I not able to collect stones?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can collect grass, wood, and sand but when it comes to things like stone I can break it but I can't collect it after.

What am I doing wrong ? How am I supposed to collect them ?

Comment: Have you tried [crafting a Pickaxe?](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Pickaxe)

Comment: I know that @Ben - I ran out of time to change it around.

Comment: This question shows poor research and is likely to be closed.

Comment: @Marco - Poor research is a downvote reason (it's right there on the tooltip), not a close reason.

Comment: @JasonBerkan I didnt say the poor research WAS the reason to vote to close. I said that the question showed poor research and that the question is likely to be closed (which are two seperate statements).

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma What would be the "close" reason ?

Comment: This is an unregistered user account and probably doesn't know the rules of the site. While poor research deserves a downvote there is no reason to close the question.

Comment: Related meta discussion: [A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5498/83262)

Comment: If Unionhawk doesn't already have it, he deserves the Reversal badge for this one.  His answer is good, even if you think the question is bad.  Give him those upvotes if you agree, that's what the button is there for.

Comment: He'll likely get the Reversal badge if he deserves it. The answer is pretty simple though, not bad but not amazing, IMO... A simple question gets a simple answer.

Comment: @pppery I don't think that this is a duplicate, the other question is about the pocket edition, while this one is about the java edition. The problem and the solution are the same, but it's technically about two different games. (I would be ok with closing this as a duplicate, because they are similar enough)

Answer (score 2):

You can punch stone all you want, but it won't drop anything. You will need to craft a pickaxe first. You can craft a wooden pickaxe in a crafting table like so:

[image: Wooden Pickaxe crafting recipe]

I suggest checking out the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/) for more information about the game in general if you're still stuck.